# Android/Java: displaying images from assets and/or internal/sd storage

Tags: java, android, android-assets, android-external-storage

I am working on an android app in which I want to display images in ImageView. At this point (during development), I have stored the images in the 'assets' folder.

The main reason for using assets is because of the `getAssets().list()` command, such that I end up with an array with the contents of the folder (I need to know how many files are in the folder and what their filenames are)

```
public boolean listAssetFiles(String path) {
    try {
        fileList = getAssets().list(path);
        numberOfFiles = fileList.length;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, I want users to import their own images into the application whilst running the application from internal and/or sd storage.

I doubt, after some googling, whether it is possible to import these images to the assets folder, but I am not sure.

I therefore have two questions:

**1) is it possible to import images, whilst running the application / or at startup, into the assets folder?**

**2) if not, how can I create an array of the filenames of a particular folder in the internal and/or sd storage.**

anyone who can give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to import images, whilst running the application / or at startup, into the assets folder?

No. Assets and resources are read-only at runtime.

> how can I create an array of the filenames of a particular folder in the internal and/or sd storage.

First, learn exactly what [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) are.

Then, get a `File` object pointing to where you want the files from. Then, call `listFiles()` on that `File` object.

If you want to allow the user to choose the directory, consider using a [file/directory picker library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created).